# Movie in which aliens/monster cause power outage and kidnap people into dark dimension to eat them

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm trying to remember a movie in which aliens or some kind of monsters were able to cause power outages. When in darkness, they'd drag their victims to the darkest corner and transfer them into some sort of a dark dimension, not unlike Upside Down in Stranger Things.

There was a group of people who figured it out. They get kidnapped one by one, including one that gets dragged under an elevator.

It's happening everywhere.

The movie ends with the main character (a woman) in an asylum for insane people... dragged into a closet. She's then shown in the dark dimension, banging on an invisible barrier, yelling for help. Some people walk into a room, don't see anyone, close the closet. When it's closed, the alien/monster bites her face. Screen goes dark.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0985025/?

Comment: @Valorum Lordi? :D

Comment: @Gallifreyan - [Yup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAh9NRGNhUU)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the 2002 Wes Craven / Robert Harmon film, *[They](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_(2002_film))*.

> In 1983, a young boy named Billy Parks (Alexander Gould) is frightened and has difficulty falling asleep after waking up from a nightmare. His mother Mary Parks (Desiree Zurowski) comes in to comfort him and assures him the monster he thinks is in the closet is imaginary. As he tries to fall asleep again he sees a dark apparition in his closet staring at him and pulls the covers on top of himself and turns on a flashlight. As he peeks outside the covers he is captured and spirited away by the mysterious apparition.
>
> n present day 2002, the plot focuses on the story of a Psychology grad student named Julia Lund (Laura Regan) and the events that turned her life upside down. As a child she experienced horrifying night terrors that manifested after witnessing her father commit suicide, but has seemingly overcome the problem. She reunites with a childhood friend, a now grown-up Billy (Jon Abrahams). In the diner Billy is constantly startled by the flickering lights as he is now deathly afraid of the dark. He tells her that he believes their night terrors are caused by something otherworldly as he was kidnapped by mysterious creatures as a child and went missing for two days. He warns her to stay out of the dark, before suddenly committing suicide.

...

> [Julia] is hospitalized at a mental institution by Dr. Booth and Paul where she is attacked once more and transported into the separate dimension she previously saw, only this time inside of a closet. Here she screams for help towards Dr. Booth and an orderly, both of whom cannot see her. The closet door is shut by Dr. Booth and the creatures proceed to attack her.

[This site](http://www.themoviespoiler.com/Spoilers/they.html) mentions the elevator scene:

> The painter is painting with many candles lit. The sprinklers come on and dowse his candles. He takes the elevator to get out of the building and after several floors he hears a noise as if it was grabbed or dragged for a short distance. He gets out of the elevator which has stopped in the middle but then he is dragged under the elevator.

Comment: Google search terms of *film creature hunts in dark dimension asylum*. This was the second result. Seeing the ending clinched it for me.

Comment: I Googled almsot the same thing (*movie monster hunt dark dimension asylum*) and after 10 pages nothing suggested this. Thank you!

Comment: You never know what a few words difference will do. :) Plus, I think Google tunes search results. Initiallly, I was thinking "Lights Out". Both were on Wikipedia's "Darkness in Media" index, but I was being too lazy to lick through to check plot summaries.

Comment: That is true, Google personalizes search results. Which is sometimes infuriating.