# What is this movie with creature scared off by bright light?

Tags: story-identification, movie

In this suspense/thriller movie which was probably early 2000s,  a blondish young woman sees a spiderlike creature crawling on the ceiling. She is later put in a mental institution, but later she is discharged because she lied that she no longer sees the creature. The movie ends with the woman alone in her bedroom, surrounded by high powered lights and lamps.

Comment: Can you remember when you watched this? How long ago it was? What the creature looked like? How come no one else saw it? If you have anything else to add you can [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possibly Boogeyman - or one of the two sequels. I've only ever seen the first hour of the initial film, there was a girl who was convinced she had a Boogeyman hidden in her ceiling. Near the start the male protagonist (who had witnessed a Boogeyman attack) slept surrounded by bright lights so it's likely the girl decided to do the same. The film was too dull to watch until the end so I don't know

Comment: I can't remember when the movie was..probably around early 2000s. The creature wasn't clearly shown.I seem to recall it resembling a crawling spider.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the boogeyman movie..The film was more on suspense, rather than horror. All i can clearly remember was the ending part with the bright lamps turned on.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155274/movie-in-which-aliens-monster-cause-power-outage-and-kidnap-people-into-dark-dim

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen the movie myself, but with some help from Google, what you are describing sounds a lot like the alternative ending to the movie [*They*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_(2002_film)#Alternate_endings)

The movie starred Lauren Rogan, who is blonde.

> **Alternate endings**
> Two alternate endings were shot but neither of them
> made it to the final cut, they include:
>
> - After the incident in the subway the film's plot cuts to nine months
>   later where Julia is shown hospitalized in a mental institution. Julia
>   manages to convince a panel of psychiatrists including Dr. Booth that
>   she has regained her sanity. She then sees one of the creatures climb
>   through an air shaft in the ceiling but continues to deny their
>   existence. **She is finally released and proceeds to set up high powered
>   lights all over her apartment room. The camera then pulls out of her
>   bedroom as she is seen sitting on her bed. A door creaks open in her
>   darkened hall and the film cuts to black.** (This ending was shown to
>   test audiences which was deleted and re-filmed after test audiences
>   responded negatively to the ending, for some reason this ending is
>   unavailable in any DVD.)
> - Julia wakes up in the mental hospital and
>   sees that all the people in her story − Dr. Booth, Sam, Billy, Terry -
>   are patients in the mental hospital and her boyfriend Paul is a doctor
>   working there. The doors to Julia's room then break open and one of
>   "them" enters and seemingly attacks her until it is realized that it
>   was all a delusion fabricated by Julia's mind and she had been
>   suffering from Schizophrenia throughout the whole movie. (Some
>   versions of the DVD and all Blu-ray versions have this ending
>   available.)

And from [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283632/alternateversions?tab=cz&ref_=tt_trv_alt), the alternative ending you remember was described as part of the work print:

> The work print features this alternate ending which is not available on DVD anywhere. When Julia is knocked out in the subway it cuts to 9 months later in a mental hospital. Julia convinces a panel of psychiatrists, including Dr. Booth, that she is cured. She sees one of the monsters climb through an air shaft in the ceiling, but continues to claim that "They" don't exist. She is released and goes home only to set up high-powered lights all over her apartment. The camera pulls out of her bedroom as she sits on her bed. A door creaks open in her darkened hall and it cuts to black.

So it sounds like you saw the movie before it was released.  And the ending you are remembering can't be found on any DVD's

Comment: Wow that's it. Thanks so much. At first, I really thought it was They 2002 film but when I watched searched it on google and even watched it online, the scenes I remember aren't there and the ending is "wrong". I searched alot about alternative endings to They, I only found the Japan version which she didn't get captured at the end but just got institutionalized.